# помогите вывести только нужные значения

Tags: python

После команды выдаются словари в очень большом количестве, ниже пример. Мне нужны вывести только те словари, symbol которых я укажу в moedas. Чтобы потом ещё это можно было перевести в DataFrame

moedas = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'EOSUSDT' , 'XRPUSDT', 'BCHUSDT', 'LTCUSDT']

client.get_ticker()

> {'symbol': 'BTTUSDC',   'priceChange': '0.00000000',
> 'priceChangePercent': '0.000',   'weightedAvgPrice': '0.00000000',
> 'prevClosePrice': '0.00277600',   'lastPrice': '0.00000000',
> 'lastQty': '0.00000000',   'bidPrice': '0.00000000',   'bidQty':
> '0.00000000',   'askPrice': '0.00000000',   'askQty': '0.00000000',
> 'openPrice': '0.00000000',   'highPrice': '0.00000000',   'lowPrice':
> '0.00000000',   'volume': '0.00000000',   'quoteVolume': '0.00000000',
> 'openTime': 1663757083378,   'closeTime': 1663843483378,   'firstId':
> -1,   'lastId': -1,   'count': 0},  {'symbol': 'ONGBNB',   'priceChange': '0.00000000',   'priceChangePercent': '0.000',
> 'weightedAvgPrice': '0.00000000',   'prevClosePrice': '0.00545000',
> 'lastPrice': '0.00000000',   'lastQty': '0.00000000',   'bidPrice':
> '0.00000000',   'bidQty': '0.00000000',   'askPrice': '0.00000000',
> 'askQty': '0.00000000',   'openPrice': '0.00000000',   'highPrice':
> '0.00000000',   'lowPrice': '0.00000000',   'volume': '0.00000000',
> 'quoteVolume': '0.00000000',   'openTime': 1663757083378,
> 'closeTime': 1663843483378,   'firstId': -1,   'lastId': -1,
> 'count': 0},  {'symbol': 'ONGBTC',   'priceChange': '-0.00000006',
> 'priceChangePercent': '-0.351',   'weightedAvgPrice': '0.00001741',
> 'prevClosePrice': '0.00001704',   'lastPrice': '0.00001702',
> 'lastQty': '16.00000000',   'bidPrice': '0.00001702',   'bidQty':
> '604.00000000',   'askPrice': '0.00001706',   'askQty':
> '604.00000000',   'openPrice': '0.00001708',   'highPrice':
> '0.00001837',   'lowPrice': '0.00001680',   'volume':
> '693239.00000000',   'quoteVolume': '12.07190028',   'openTime':
> 1665215802610,   'closeTime': 1665302202610,   'firstId': 9646849,
> 'lastId': 9651026,   'count': 4178},  {'symbol': 'ONGUSDT',
> 'priceChange': '-0.00260000',   'priceChangePercent': '-0.780',
> 'weightedAvgPrice': '0.33791046',   'prevClosePrice': '0.33340000',
> 'lastPrice': '0.33060000',   'lastQty': '574.00000000',   'bidPrice':
> '0.33070000',   'bidQty': '1895.00000000',   'askPrice': '0.33100000',
> 'askQty': '906.00000000',   'openPrice': '0.33320000',   'highPrice':
> '0.35740000',   'lowPrice': '0.32620000',   'volume':
> '3371982.00000000',   'quoteVolume': '1139427.99570000',   'openTime':
> 1665215882736,   'closeTime': 1665302282736,   'firstId': 16813661,
> 'lastId': 16820414,   'count': 6754},

Answer (score 0):

вам это что ли нужно?

```
data = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
moedas = ['x', 'z']

res = {key: value for key, value in data.items() if key in moedas}
```

оно же:

```
res = dict(elem for elem in data.items() if elem[0] in moedas)
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это то что вам нужно:

```py
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client


api_key = 'your api key'
api_secret = 'your api secret'

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

moedas = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'EOSUSDT' , 'XRPUSDT', 'BCHUSDT', 'LTCUSDT']
# получаем список только нужных нам пар из moedas
tickers = [client.get_ticker(**{'symbol': f'{symbol}'}) for symbol in moedas]
# создаём DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tickers)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    symbol   priceChange priceChangePercent weightedAvgPrice  prevClosePrice       lastPrice  ...          quoteVolume       openTime      closeTime     firstId      lastId    count
0  BTCUSDT  -65.91000000             -0.339   19430.92694098  19461.51000000  19395.30000000  ...  1967885982.30194210  1665219315231  1665305715231  1940432906  1943090439  2657534
1  ETHUSDT  -10.52000000             -0.794    1319.17784487   1325.63000000   1315.11000000  ...   251945475.41172100  1665219315455  1665305715455   986635077   986987589   352513
2  EOSUSDT    0.00000000              0.000       1.11616941      1.12500000      1.12500000  ...     5536801.75340000  1665219315378  1665305715378   214666451   214680649    14199
3  XRPUSDT   -0.00300000             -0.578       0.51673515      0.51940000      0.51630000  ...   134912496.57490000  1665219315977  1665305715977   478322977   478532996   210020
4  BCHUSDT   -0.60000000             -0.509     117.20027603    117.80000000    117.20000000  ...     3733931.41180000  1665219315985  1665305715985   133623182   133635958    12777
5  LTCUSDT    0.04000000              0.075      53.02665147     53.21000000     53.26000000  ...    11386192.91461000  1665219317894  1665305717894   254311426   254352375    40950
```